# Using $.getScript to load d3.js

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I am trying to load the d3js script using

`$.getScript('http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js', function(data, textStatus) { console.log(textStatus); return true });`

which is correctly returning the "success" status.

I have already set

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  cache: true,
  async: false
});
```

so that the file is completely loaded before trying to use it.

But I am getting "TypeError: names.map(...).join is not a function" in my console window.

Has anyone encountered this situation? Is there something special that I need to do to get the file to load correctly?

I also tried

```
var se = document.createElement('script');
se.type = "text/javascript";
se.src = "http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(se);
```

with the same results.

I have no problem with

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>
```

but in this application, it is not an option.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Try doing this : Open your browser JS console, paste in the first code snippet and execute it. In my browsers (FF & Chrome) this causes no error messages. If the same happens in your case, it might be that the error is the result of a problem somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for this? I can't recreate this either - see http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/EhESp/4/

Answer (score 1):

Try to start working in the callback function

```
$.getScript('http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js', function(data, textStatus) { 

//Start Using d3 functions here.

 return true 

});
```

You need to be sure that the script was loaded...

Comment: Worked for me. I have another version of d3 loaded on the same page, so would you know how to assign this version of d3 the name d3v5?